# How to keep the image Drawn in PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Hey everyone, a new guy here in C#.Net.

I'm trying to make an application like Ms Paint, of course much simpler, and I'm stuck.

The problem is this.

In pictureBox, I'm drawing grid lines on the PictureBox, after that I'm reading a .map(A Mapper3 file) and want to draw onto grid lines, but When I draw the map, The grid lines disappers.

I think the problem is because of the PictureBox Image becomes null while I'm drawing the map. How can I overcome this, is there any tricks?

Thanks for the replies from now on, and sorry for my bad English...

My best Regards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you using winforms? If yes, you actually dont need picture box for working area. I think  more appropriate would be [Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) class on form or panel. You have lost lines because of form repaint circle, put your drawing code into form paint handler and picture would be repainted when it needed. In some cases you can need to manual trigger repaint circle, for this purposes you should use [Invalidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.invalidate.aspx) method of your form.

For example, add this code to paint handler:

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Drawing vertical lines
        for (int x = 5; x < this.ClientRectangle.Width; x+=5)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Gray, new Point(x, 0), new Point(x, this.ClientRectangle.Height));
        }

        // Drawing horisontal lines
        for (int y = 5; y < this.ClientRectangle.Width; y += 5)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Gray, new Point(0, y), new Point(this.ClientRectangle.Width,y));
        }
    }
```

You also may use Graphics in button click handler this way:

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle);

g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Beige, new Rectangle(10, 10, 10, 10));
```

But in this case all you have drawn would be erased during form's repaint circle and you will have to repeint it in form paint handler

**[EDIT]**
Ok, for example you have pictureBox1 on your form, you can easly draw into it with help of [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) class in this way:

```
// Draw into bitmap
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(150, 150);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, new Rectangle(25, 75, 10, 30));

// Set bitmap into picture box
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

In this case you have no need to redraw your paintings, picture box would do it for you. Dont forget to set `BackColor` ot picture box to `Transparent` if you prefer to show paintings from below of picture box.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes I'm using winforms, but honestly, I don't get the idea using Canvas class. Can you make it wider what you mean?

Comment: @Un_NatMenDim: First of all, sorry for my mistake I have messed Canvas with Graphics. I have edited my answer

Comment: Ok, I get it, the drawings are remained, but the rectangles are overlapped with the pictureBox. The problem is I have to draw anything I need into the pictureBox, so the drawing in the PictureBox has to be kept in somewhere or that kind of operation, but what is it? Here's the question :)

Comment: @Un_NatMenDim: Ok, now I got your question, Ive updated my answer once more

Comment: Thx for help, I've already made the same thing as you edited. it works fine, but When draw another thing onto pictureBox(such as ellipses), the Rectangle still disappears although I set BackColor to Transparent :/

Comment: @Un_NatMenDim: Yes, you have appropriate result. To add new painting into picture box dont create new bitmap, just read it from `Image` property of picture box and draw new stuff on it

Comment: Oh, do you mean smt. like
`code`
Bitmap bmp = (BitMap)p_box_map.Image;
`code`
I tried but nothing changed, can you show how to make it please?

Comment: Oh yea, I did it. 
The main point is to use only one Bitmap. Man I really am grateful for yor help, really thanks :)

Comment: @Un_NatMenDim: You are welcome. several years ago I have fought against same problems, Im very pleasent that my experience can help you

Answer (score 1):

You have to draw everything including the grid lines whenever the paint event raised, if you are concerned about performance you may detect the clipping area and only draw that portion.

Good luck.

Comment: Thax for the reply. The thing is I'm not drawing in a pictureBox_Draw event. I'm drawing both the map and the grids in button_Click's events, and I have to do it using with these buttons. Is there any way using both pictureBox_Draw and Button_Click events together?

Comment: Sorry I know this is too late I wasn't around stackoverflow lately, anyways the idea is you can draw over the PictureBox in the button click event but the PictureBox maybe overlapped with some other windows or you minimize the whole window and then maximize it and as a result the PictureBox needs to redraw its graphics and the Paint event is raised and if you are doing some custom drawing over the PictureBox here you should do your work.